# Google Inspector Showing Different Widths

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web page and when I look at the page through the Google Inspector on the page hosted on Github pages versus the page hosted on a local server, I get different window widths.
[here is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrT4h.png)

Additionally, here is a link to my project: [click here to view it on Github](https://iccir919.github.io/coursera_html-css-javascript/module2_assignment/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you zoomed in your page and this is why you get 424.667px instead of 667px. If I zoom your page I get approximately same results ;)

[image: Different box size according to zoom]

Comment: This is the answer (in case any one else has this silly question in the future). Thank you for your help Anton!